# personalize my iAds

Tags: iphone, iad

what need to study/know before
personalize own iAd with NOT using the template which provided by iads producer?

Try to find some tutorial from internet,
but seems like not able to find any tutorials about it,
wish to get some guide here :(

Answer (score 1):

as far as I got it, you want to display custom content in ADBannerView. If that's the case, then this is not possible. after setting yourself as ADBannerView delegate, all you basically do is handling delegate methods by sliding it in or out of screen depending on whether the content's been loaded. but you don't have control over what's loaded